# Android: How to show an opengl scene to textureview

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-textureview

I need to render the opengl scene to a TextureView in my layout. I can render it by GlSurfaceView like below :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Create a GLSurfaceView instance and set it
    // as the ContentView for this Activity
    mGLView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this);
    setContentView(mGLView);
}
```

But i need to render the openGL scene into a textureview. How can i do that?